# Multiple different wallets connected to same monero node

Tags: rpc, monero-wallet-rpc, watch-only-wallet, view-only

I'm trying to connect multiple wallet-RPC to the same monero node. I have started two separated terminals in order to test the setup and started it with the following command:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 --wallet-file /path/to/my/wallet/wallet-viewonly --password "" --disable-rpc-login --daemon-host node.moneroworld.com:18089
```

Then on two web pages, I'm showing the addresses to see that they are connected to RPC. What is happening is that no matter which wallet-rpc first got connected this address is shown on the page.

So, I have two addresses, two pages and two terminals for monero-wallet-rpc. The expected result is when both terminals are connected on both pages to see those addresses. Instead on both pages is shown same address -> the first connected to the node.

Can I run multiple wallet-rpc's and connect them to the node on the same machine? How can be accomplished this?

Comment: have you run the two monero wallet rpc instance in two different ports?

Comment: Yes, I've tried `--rpc-bind-port 18083`. Still first connected to the daemon is shown on both pages. Very strange.

Answer (score 3):

You can run multiple monero-wallet-rpc processes on the same machine (or different ones), and connect them to a single node (which can be either on the same machine again, or a different one). You don't have to do anything special for this, though it's best if the monero-wallet-rpc processes don't run off the same wallet file, or they'll overwrite each other's wallet cache when they exit, which is usually not what you want.

Now, it's pretty unclear what you mean by "I'm showing the addresses to see that they are connected to RPC. What is happening is that no matter which wallet-rpc first got connected this address is shown on the page.". What are these addresses ? Incoming connection IP addresses ? Wallet addresses ? How are you obtaining those addresses ? You really need to give information if you expect people to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Simply I have created 2 view only wallets. Then I've added them to the database and by using php I'm querying the database. Then the PHP checks if the address is connected and communicated with monero daemon. On page, I just see `The address XYZXSZ is connected/not connected.`.

Comment: Describe "checks if the address is connected and communicated".

Comment: For example, If is connected with rpc to the node I can see if funds are received

Comment: I am not  interested in *why* you want to know, but *how* this check is done. You can find a bug in some code if you know *how* it is done, not why (though sometimes knowing why tells you it should be removed, but that's not the case here).

Comment: I'm using this repo https://github.com/PsychicCat/monero-php